# Amazon EMR - Is Spark dataframe.cache() stored in core nodes only, or also on task nodes?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr

I'm running on AWS EMR Spark (v2) and calculated a large dataframe. When the dataframe.cache() (which is lazy) kicks-in would it be performed on the task nodes, or would the data frame be moved around to the core nodes for caching?

Comment: Do you mean by local node?

Comment: EMR has task nodes and core nodes (with hdfs).